# R: If I have two matrices, one with nearly the same columns but mixed up. How can I effectively map the two matrices?

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, optimization

Of the two matrices have one has i) the columns in different orders and ii) entire columns (every elements in the column) has the opposite different signs. An example would be

```
A = 1 2
    3 4

b = 1.99 -1.02
    3.99 -2.99
```

How can I re-order b such that it looks like:

```
b = 1.02 1.99
    2.99 3.99
```

Is there away to do this quickly in R?

Comment: Since you are changing the signs of some of the elements of `b`, referring to this as *reordering* `b` seems misleading. The problem isn't very clear. In what way does `A` tell you how to change `b`? A single example isn't an adequate specification.

Comment: "different order" is vague

Answer (score 1):

You could treat it as an optimization problem -- minimize the absolute difference between the two matrices by reordering the columns in one of the matrices.

Example data

```
A <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4), nrow = 2)
A
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

b <- matrix(c(-2.99, 3.99, -1.02, 1.99), nrow = 2) 
b
      [,1]  [,2]
[1,] -2.99 -1.02
[2,]  3.99  1.99
```

Optimization / search

```
# Data frame with a row for every possible column arrangement

ordering <- (expand.grid(rep(list(1:ncol(A)), ncol(A))))
ordering

  Var1 Var2
1    1    1
2    2    1
3    1    2
4    2    2

# Create a function to compute the difference for a particular arrangement

loss <- function(i) {
    ord <- unlist(ordering[i, ])
    sum(abs(abs(A) - abs(b[, ord])))
}

# Find the best arrangement
result <- optimize(loss, 1:nrow(ordering))

result$minimum    # row index from the data frame
[1] 2.145956

# Extract the row to get the actual solution

solution <- unname(unlist(ordering[result$minimum, ]))

solution
[1] 2 1
```

Verify

```
A
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

b[, solution]
      [,1]  [,2]
[1,] -1.02 -2.99
[2,]  1.99  3.99
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your matrices are as small as they are in your examples, you could change the order of the columns the following way:

Your example indicates you want to switch the first column and the second column. We can do that by reordering the column indexes like so:

```
b <- b[ , c(2, 1)]
```

`c(2, 1)` indicates that from now on, column 2 will be displayed as the first column and then column 1 will be displayed as the second column. We specify this in the column portion of the index operator and leave the row portion blank.

If we want to change the sign of an entire column, we can perform operations on specific columns like so:

```
b[ , 1] <- -1*b[ , 1]
```

This makes it so that every value in what is now the first column gets multiplied by -1.

If the matrix you're dealing with is much bigger, this is probably an impractical approach.